# DB2 connection issue while upgrading to Java 11

Tags: java, db2, java-11

While upgrading from Java 7 to 11, getting following exception while connecting to DB2. Using hibernate ORM to connect with DB2 its working with Java 7 but not Java 11.

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2537)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2367)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2362)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1260)
**Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][t4][1037][12307][3.58.82] Exception occurred during DECFLOAT conversion. See attached Throwable for details. ERRORCODE=-4220, SQLSTATE=null**

**Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.a: [jcc][converters][606][13302]Decfloat conversion requires JDK1.5**
```

Comment: This does not look like a connection issue. And it is missing details. Have you  the required SDK as in the error message?

Answer (score 1):

Your exception text shows you are using an antique version of db2jcc.jar , version `[3.58.82]`. This comes from Db2 v9.7 fp1 , which is no longer supported by IBM.

In your development and test environments first, Upgrade to `db2jcc4.jar` at version 4.28.11 (or higher) as supplied [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-jdbc-driver-versions-and-downloads)
and retry.

If you are connecting to a mainframe database ( Db2-for-Z/OS ) then you will need to do one of these to handle the licensing:

- use a relevant version of the db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar file (get it from your Passport Advantage site administrator, or helpful Db2 DBA for Z/OS who will know the version of the target system and the ways to access it.
- or if your site has an unlimited-editition license for Db2-connect then get your DBA to run the `db2connectactivate`tool.
- or connect via a pre-existing Db2-connect gateway (in this case you don't need the license file on your client environment).

You do not need that license file if the database is hosted on Linux/Unix/Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.

After using latest version of db2jcc4.jar then I get exception as

org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory ([jcc][t4][10509][13454][4.27.25] Connection to the data server failed. The IBM Data Server for JDBC and SQLJ license was invalid
or was not activated for the DB2 for z/OS subsystem. If you are connecting directly to
the data server and using DB2 Connect Unlimited Edition for System z, perform the
activation step by running the activation program in the license activation kit.
If you are using any other edition of DB2 Connect, obtain the license file,
db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar, from the license activation kit, and follow the installation
directions to include the license file in the class path. ERRORCODE=-4230, SQLSTATE=42968)

Does latest version required license jar file?